# ATG refund payment type

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

While returning a item using returns manager is it possible to assign refund to a new payment group and associate it with order ?

For example if the order payment is done using credit card then I need to use cash for refund during return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no this cannot be done with ATG ootb as it only supports credit card refunds and/or store card refunds.  More information on this can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Service.10-2/ATGCommerceServiceCenterUserGuide/html/s0503issuingrefunds01.html).

It really depends on the precise business requirements as to how you go about solving this.  The suggestions below might not be sufficient to meet your particular requirements.

What you are trying to do is certainly possible with customization but it will potentially add a lot of complexity.  Things to consider:

- Order History.  You will need to display the additional payment group information
- Repeat Orders.  Might add some complexity here.
- Payment method.  You will probably have to add your own payment method which can be complicated.  Information on how to do this can be found here.

A simpler approach might be to add some new `PaymentGroup` [states](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGCommProgGuide/html/s1408paymentgroupstates01.html) which you update when you issue a refund e.g. SETTLED_WITH_PARTIAL_CASH_REFUND or SETTLED_WITH_FULL_CASH_REFUND.  You could extend the paymentGroup to include a partial refund amount for record keeping purposes.